# general solution of $xy''+(1-2x)y'+(x-1)y=e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help to solve this problem:

$$xy''+(1-2x)y'+(x-1)y=e^x$$

Given that one solution of the corresponding homogeneous problem is $y_1=e^x$

Comment: you might want to take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

The rhs suggest me to set $y(x)=z(x) e^x$. Doing so, you arrive to $$x z''(x)+z'(x)=1$$ which can be changed to a quite simple first order differential equation .

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{another hint}$

$$
xy'' + (1-2x)y' + (x-1)y = xy'' - xy' + (1-x)y' - (1-x)y\\
= x(y''-y') + (1-x)(y'-y) \\
= x\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(y'-y\right) + (1-x)(y'-y) = \mathrm{e}^{x}
$$
let $z = \left(y'-y\right) $ we find
$$
x\dfrac{dz}{dx} + (1-x)z = \mathrm{e}^{x}
$$
or
$$
z(x)\mathrm{e}^{\ln x - x} = \int \mathrm{e}^{x}\mathrm{e}^{\ln x - x} dx +\lambda\\
z(x)x\mathrm{e}^{-x}= \int x dx +\lambda
$$
so 
$$
y' - y = \left[\dfrac{x^2}{2} + \lambda\right]\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{x}}{x}
$$